# Combine Observables into a single Observable from a dynamic array of Observable?

Tags: firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, rxfire

Summary: essentially I need something like `from Users where usergroupIds in [1,3,5]`.

Given `usergroupIds$` emit an array of group IDs `[1,3,5]`

I want to union all users by `userids` in `usergroupIds` and combine the userIds (distinct)

Here is what I came up with:

```
usergroupIds$.subscribe(usergroupIds => {
    const users$s = usergroupIds.map(gid => createUsersObservable(gid))
    //  [users$ in group 1, users$ in group 3, users$ in group 5]
    const users$ = combineLatest(...user$s).pipe(
        distinct(user => user.id)
    )
})

createUsersObservable = gid => 
  collectionData(db.collection('users').where('groupId', '==', gid)) // rxFire firestore
```

Unsubscribe & resubscribe `users$` every time on change seems wrong?

Is it possible to express `users$` fully in RxJS without creating it in a subscription every time?

**Update:**
With help from @FanCheung:

```
combinedUsers$ = userGroupIds$.pipe(
        switchMap(userGroupIds => {
            const users$s = userGroupIds.map(groupId =>
                createUsersObservable(groupId))
            return combineLatest(...users$s)
        })
```

However, since usersObservable emit an array of users at a time, The combinedUsers$ results in somthing like `[[userA, userB], [userB, userC], [userA, userD]]` which I don't mind to carry out the extra processing on subscribe:

```
combinedUsers$.subscribe(combinedUsers => {
        const userMap = {}
        for (const users of combinedUsers) 
            users.forEach(user => (userMap[user.id] = user))
        const uniqueUsers = Object.values(userMap)

        // update UI to uniqueUsers
    })
```

However, is there a way to use somehow flatten the results of `combinedUsers$`, and then carry out the `distinct` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this work. Basically it fires when usergroupIds$ emits and thus you get your new dynamic observable. `shareReplay` is needed if you always want the source observable `usergroupdIds$` to emit the last saved value when subscribed

```
usergroupIds$.pipe(
shareReplay(1),
switchMap(usergroupIds => {
    const users$Array = usergroupIds.map(gid => createUsersObservable(gid))
    //  [users$ in group 1, users$ in group 3, users$ in group 5]
   return forkJoin(...users$Array).pipe(
        map(arr=>[].concat(...arr)),
        switchMap(arr=>from(arr)),
        distinct(user => user.id)
    )
})
)
```

Comment: Tried this but i get [[usersInGroup1, usersInGroup2, usersInGroup3]]. Help? Thanks

Comment: @Henry  Changed combinelatest to forkjoin and these three line should make filtering work  
       `map(arr=>[].concat(...arr)),
        switchMap(arr=>from(arr)),
        distinct(user => user.id)`

Comment: Can you pls explain what does the `map(arr=>[].concat(...arr))` line do? Why is it copying the array into an empty array, wouldn't that still make 3 separate arrays?

Comment: concat takes multiple array as argument, you start with an empty array [] and `...arr` basically explode the arrays into arguments. your array will become [].concat(arr1,arr2,arr3) and flattened
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Answer (score 0):

So you don't want to be making separate requests to `createUsersObservable` every time `usergroupIds$` emits. This sounds like a good usecase for `mergeScan`:

```
usergroupIds$.pipe(
  mergeScan((users, user) => createUsersObservable().pipe(
    map(user => [user, ...users]),
  ), []),
);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-8zybdu

Comment: Performant in terms of what? It makes just one `createUsersObservable()` call per emission from `usergroupIds$` so in that case yes.